# How to avoid long paths in code built with CMake

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake to link and build my C++ project, and in said project I am using the `fstream` library to read from a file. However, when passing the path of the file to my code, I am forced to use a long string such as `"../../../../folder/folder/folder/file"` to properly reference which file I want opened. I presume this is because my `.exe` that CMake creates is buried deep, "far" away from my source code, which is why I would have to backtrack so much.

I am wondering if there is something I could put in my `CMakeLists.txt` to potentially allow for the shortening of this inclusion path.

To save myself some time I have not included my file structure as of now, but if it is needed in order for a solution to be formed I certainly can edit and add it in. I do not necessarily need a case-specific solution, rather just a generalized method in which I could go about doing this.

Comment: The best thing to do is probably to pass that path in as a command line argument and use a path in the CMakeLists.txt relative to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` or even better (if applicable) `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:my_exe>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like CMake doesn't provide such functionality , CMake doesn't do much with  execution of your application.

So, For solution you have following

> can either create a shell script to copy the file into the desired location which can be picked by the executable and shell script can be run while make process

> pass it as a commandline argument to your c++ executable.

> create a macro with this location and use this macro in the source file  : -  CMake can help you in this
>
> > Using add_compile_definitions( ...)